# c# application do not send requests without fiddler

Tags: c#

I have this application coded in c#. The application uses httpclient and webrequests methods.

The problem I am facing is when I run the application it do not actually send requests. But, when I run the fiddler then run the application it sends requests and works flawlessly. What could be the reason?

This sends request.

```
public void Login()
        {

            Loginfirst();

            //Create cookies

            // create request
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www." + server_site + ".com/login");
            //request.CookieContainer = cookieJar;

            request.Method = "POST";
            string postData = "email=" + Username + "&password=" + Password + "&remember=false&request_type=ajax";
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);


            //set the contenttype property
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = true;
            //request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
            //set header
            request.UserAgent = User_Agent;
            request.Accept = "application/json";
            request.Headers.Add("X-Requested-with", "XMLHttpRequest");


            request.Headers.Add("Cookie", m_cookies);

            log_file("line 975" + m_cookies);


            //request.Headers["Cookie"] = "rlogin=" + Username + "";
            request.KeepAlive = false;
            //set the contentlength property of the WebRequest
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            // get the stream containing returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            // Write the data to the request stream
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            //close the Stream object
            dataStream.Close();
            // get the response


            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                cookieCount = cookieJar.Count;
                String setcookieheader = response.Headers[HttpResponseHeader.SetCookie];

                Console.WriteLine(setcookieheader);

                foreach (Cookie cookie in response.Cookies)
                {
                    if (cookie.Name == "PHPSESSID")
                    {                        
                        PHPSESSID = cookie.Value;
                        logged = true;
                        grid_status = "Log OK";
                        log_file("Grid Status OK");
                    }
                }


                //display statuts
                //Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);



                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Status OK");                    
                    log_file("Status OK 1022");
                    all_other_requests("profile");
                    all_other_requests("profile_status");
                    all_other_requests("faster");

                    //all_other_requests("fasterstart");

                    real_timer.Elapsed += Real_timer_Elapsed;
                    real_timer.Interval = 1000;
                    real_timer.Enabled = true;
                    real_timer.Start();


                }
                else
                {
                    Login();

                }

                dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                //open the stream using a streamreader for easy access.
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
                //read the content
                //response_object = reader.ReadToEnd().Replace("\\/", "/").Replace("\"", "\'");
                response_object = reader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(response_object);
                reader.Close();
                response.Close();


            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {

                log_file("Line 1055" + e.Message);

                if (e.Status == WebExceptionStatus.Timeout)
                {
                    Login();
                    return;
                }
            }


            //dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(response_object);

            /*
            if (result.response.result=="bad_auth")
            {
                logged = false;         
            }

            if(result.response.result == "ok_auth")
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("logged in");
                Session = result.response.session;
                logged = true;
                all_other_requests("get");
            } */



        }


t0 = new Task(bb0.Login);
                t0.Start();

    t1 = new Task(bb1.Login);
                t1.Start();
    t2 = new Task(bb2.Login);
                t2.Start();
```

Task t0 works without fiddler.
Task t1 wont work without fiddler.
Task t2 wont work without fiddler.

You can only successfully one task at a time. Like if you run t2 then  cant work with t1, t2 vice verse.

Comment: what is the result of  `GetResponse()` ?

Comment: Did fiddler once close abnormally? Fiddler changes proxy settings. Check if the settings are still on.

Comment: No, it never closed abnormally. The only thing I am noticing is when you run the fillder the app behaves good then you close the fiddler run the app then it never works.  To make sure the fiddler proxy removed. I checked by going to internet explorer properties. LAN Settings. Automatic detect settings checked and User a proxy is unchecked.

Comment: Then what the error was?

Comment: @weichch I just cant grasp over my head.  You run the app without fiddler. It wont work. Opens the fiddler then run  the app works. :( I tested it on more than 3 computers. Same issue. Works only when fiddler installed and opened. no fiddler no requests.

Comment: @weichchcan can you look at updated code and message?

Comment: Then another question: is there anything special in your fiddler? Like an auto responder?

Comment: @weichch there is nothing special in auto responder. I execute 3 tasks. only one of works at any given time and rest break.  There was error created in application event on windows. System.Net.WebException
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(System.Net.TransportContext ByRef)
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()

Comment: please add this to your code and tell me the result: `request.Proxy = null;`

Comment: What is the value of `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol`? If you change that to Tls12, would it help?

Comment: @SinaHoseinkhani I tried this and the application behave's the same way. I created 3 tasks. When I run these. Only one of the task can successfully execute  to the end. The other 2 tasks unsuccessful.

Comment: It would be helpful if you provide me with the result of `(HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()` in `response` when the code breaks.

Comment: @SinaHoseinkhani The OP's code fails on `GetRequestStream` which is when connecting to the server / preparing **request** stream as per the comments he replied to mine.

Comment: @weichch: if he is getting error there it means he is not sending the right parameters to server.

Comment: Just to share my thoughts here - Fiddler acts as a proxy server, which can change how the connection is established between the client and the server. For example, if your server expects a secure connection protocol, but your client does not offer, then if you connect your client directly to server, you get errors. Whereas if you connect your client to Fiddler, Fiddler connects to server this might not happen because Fiddler changes the connection. If I'm not over thinking, this might be a direction.

Comment: @SinaHoseinkhani However, that might not explain why it works when fiddler is there :)

Comment: @learningprogram in this line `string postData = "email=" + Username + "&password=" + Password + "&remember=false&request_type=ajax";` replace `Username` and `Password` with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Username)` and `HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Password)`

Comment: @weichch do you think fiddler handing multi connection differently? The tasks t1, t2, t3 calls the same login function. If i only run t1 at a time it works. but if i execute t1,t2,t3 at the same time application crashing the program. Error in event log says The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.Net.WebException
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetRequestStream(System.Net.TransportContext ByRef)

In this experiment not used fiddler. I can execute one task at a time. If i try multiple program crashes.

Comment: Well I seen cases fiddler slows requests down so  requests survived race conditions in server application. Not sure if you have those though. But it might be something else to look at.

Answer (score 1):

This only creates the request object.  You have to call `GetResponse()` or `BeginGetResponse()` to actually send the request to the server.

```
WebResponse reponse = request.GetResponse();
```

Comment: can you look at updated code and message? I execute simultaneous tasks.  Only one the tasks fully function. rest of the tasks break and dont function.